# A basic question on orthogonal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $X$ be a subspace. Let
$$\langle u,y\rangle=0 \forall u $$ with the property that $$\langle u,x\rangle =0 \;\forall x \in X$$ where $u,y \in V$.  Then I need to prove that $y \in X$.

This looks trivial intuitively. But finding it difficult to prove it. I guess I need to write $y$ as a combination of elements of $X$.

Actually I am trying to prove that orthogonal complement of an orthogonal complement of a subspace is a subset of that subspace (actually it is equal, but I have proved the other part)

Comment: This isn't true. What if $u=0$?

Comment: i corrected it.

Comment: You perhaps mean "you need to proof or find under which condition $y\in X$?

Comment: You have defined $X$ as $<u,x>=0 $. So by definition $y\in X$

Comment: Some MathJax advice:

`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: This is not the definition of $X$. I am given that $u$ is perpendicular to the all the vectors in $X$. I need to prove that if there is any other vector which is perpendicular to $u$ that vector must be in $X$. I guess I need to use the vector space property somehow. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Consider what happens when $X$ is the $x$-axis, $y$ is the vector $\langle 0,1,0\rangle$, and $u$ is the vector $\langle 0,0,1\rangle$. $\hspace{.72 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: I have changed the problem definition. Is it true now ?

Comment: No, it only follows that $y$ is in the [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $X$. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer : Actually I am trying to prove that orthogonal complement of an orthogonal complement of a vector is a subset of that vector (actually it is equal, but I have proved the other part)

Comment: The orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of a vector is the _subspace spanned by_ that vector. $\:$ Your question is much closer to the issue of taking the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of a _subspace_, but asks for a stronger conclusion than is actually true. $\:$ It follows from your assumptions that $y$ is in the closure of $X$, but $y$ is not necessarily in $X$ itself. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: But I have been asked to prove that orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement of a subspace is the subspace itself in the exercise of an optimization book

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10253/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-prasenjit)

Comment: @RickyDemer: got the proof using the uniqueness property.

Comment: @prasenjit If you can answer your own question please do so, so that the question is more helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w \in (V^{\bot})^{\bot}$. I need to prove that $w \in V$.

Now, $w$ can be expressed uniquely as $w= v + v'$ where $v \in V$ and $v' \in V^{\bot}$. Now, because $V^{\bot}$ and $(V^{\bot})^{\bot}$ are complement of each other 
$$\langle w, v' \rangle=0$$ which implies $v'=\theta_{v}$ using the fact that $\langle v, v' \rangle$=0. This implies $w=v$ thus $w \in V$

Comment: Of course, your third sentence needs $V$ to be closed (which it will be as long as it's finite dimensional). $\hspace{.59 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: In the book I am following, the definition of orthogonal complement of a vector space is defined like that.

Answer (score 0):

We have $y\in X  \Rightarrow \langle u,y \rangle=0 $, need to show that $\langle u,y \rangle=0  \Rightarrow y\in X  $. I think this depends on $X$, if e.g. $X$ is a 2D subspace in 3D $V$, then I guess it's true, while it is not true if $X$ is a 1D subspace in 3D $V$.

Comment: i have changed the problem definition. is it true now ?

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel of $V$ has one than more dimension (lets say $n > 1$), $X$ could be a subspace with dimension $1$, and $y$ could belong to $Y$, where $\operatorname{Ker}\{V\} = X \oplus Y$. Therefore $y \notin X$.

On the other hand, if the kernel of $V$ has dimension one or less, then it must be true that $y \in X$, because $\operatorname{Ker}\{V\} = X$.